# WebMatrix PHP socket_create causing 500 error

Tags: php, udp, webmatrix

As my question states, I can't figure out why, but while using WebMatrix to do PHP development, I get a 500 Error page whenever I try to run the following code:

`socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)`

Any ideas why, or how to fix?

Comment: You should configure PHP in such a way that you can read the actual error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that has this problem in future, you need to ensure that the php_sockets.dll extension is installed in your php.ini directory. Just add another line under the extentions title with the correct dll.

Thanks!